# could someone please give me step by step instructions on how to get a java applet properly signed

Tags: java, applet, signed

i need help with signing a java applet properly. the reason why iam saying 'properly' is that i have already tried generating a key using keytool and then signing the .jar file with it but it just doesnt work.iam using java 1.7. Any help will be greatly appreciated ...

Comment: Please provide more information then "it doesn't work" how are you signing it exactly?

Comment: hi there, ramhound.. i have mentioned a couple of comments down below for you to take a look at.. basically what i have mentioned is that i  have used the keytool utility for making the key with the following syntax: "keytool -genkey -alias me"  and then signed my Jar file, which gets made automatically by NETBEANS 7 IDE, using "jarsigner -javalibrary.jar me" command.When i try to access the applet using: <APPLET name="test" id="test" code=java_plugin.class archive=JavaLibrary.jar width=500 height=100 style="border-style:solid"> <param name="MAYSCRIPT" value="true" />
</APPLET>, it doesnt work

Comment: the code in the appet's .class file is as follows : String msg=""; 
       File fileobject;
       RandomAccessFile file;
        try
       {
       fileobject=new File(filename);
       file=new RandomAccessFile(fileobject,"r");
       }
       catch(Exception | Error e)
       {
       msg=""+e;
       }

       return msg;................. when i run this applet, i get the security exception even though i did sign the JAR file and ran the applet when the browser's security pop up came up. hope this helps......... thanks

Answer (score 3):

you mean, you want some sort of Tutorial for signing JAR files?

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/signindex.html

Comment: hi, there .. thanks for trying to help me out here.. I have tried all the steps that most of the websites tell you to do..here is a list of them... 
E:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_06\bin>keytool -genkey -alias private_key2
E:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_06\bin>keytool -list
private_key2, Sep 5, 2012, PrivateKeyEntry,
Certificate fingerprint (SHA1): 82:9B:84:30:E0:93:37:0E:C3:85:BC:DB:FC:B0:64:4A:
80:47:A7:15
E:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_06\bin>jarsigner JavaLibrary.jar private_key2
Enter Passphrase for keystore:
Warning:
The signer certificate will expire within six months.

Comment: after trying the above steps .. i get the signed JAR file made.. i copy that JAR file and the .class file on the IIS7 web server folder and then i access the applet with the following HTML code::: <APPLET name="test" id="test" code=java_plugin.class archive=JavaLibrary.jar width=500 height=100 style="border-style:solid">
<param name="MAYSCRIPT" value="true" />
</APPLET>.............. try i run the above code in my browser i get the java security alert asking me if i want to run the applet... i run the applet but still my java code is not able to access a local file for reading it.

Comment: the code inside the .class file of the java applet is as follows :::: try
       {
       fileobject=new File(filename);
       file=new RandomAccessFile(fileobject,"r");
       }
       catch(Exception | Error e)
       {
       msg=""+e;
       }

       return msg;.......... this java code creates an exception even though i had used a signed applet for it.. iam using IIS7, windows 7, IE8 and java 1.7... i hope this is all the info that you need to help me out..... thanks

Comment: have you tried running it outside of the browser? Does your browser capable of handling it?

Have you also tried to just run your applet without signing it?

have you also tried verifying the singed jar from the command line?

Comment: i did run the applet though the Netbeans IDE 7 which uses the applet viewer to run the applet and it works fine. i have used both mozilla firefox 15.0 and IE8 but my applet doesnt run in either one of these. both the browsers do support java and allow other signed applets to run just fine. I also verified the .JAR file and it passes with no error....

Comment: E:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_06\bin>jarsigner -verify JavaLibrary.jar -verbose
s k      283 Wed Sep 05 01:04:00 IST 2012 META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
         410 Wed Sep 05 01:04:00 IST 2012 META-INF/PRIVATE_.SF
        1037 Wed Sep 05 01:04:00 IST 2012 META-INF/PRIVATE_.DSA
           0 Tue Sep 04 19:08:52 IST 2012 META-INF/
smk      678 Tue Sep 04 01:26:14 IST 2012 java_plugin$1.class
smk     2493 Tue Sep 04 19:08:52 IST 2012 java_plugin.class
  
jar verified..... so it gets verified just fine..i dont know what exactly is it that i am doing wrong.

Comment: Well, it seems like everything is working except when you connect it to your browser.

Maybe your browsers have a setting that doesn't trust jars for some reason. I'm not sure what that issue could be. Perhaps they only trust signed jars from certain sources?

Comment: try to get your app to work in the browser, without Verifying

Comment: hi there ... are so many days of researching, i have finally figured out what was going wrong.. it turns out that even though your applets is all signed , still it wont be able to get the security clearance that it needs since its being accessed through javascript code, atleast that is what i understood so far. so to get the security clearance that you need you need to put the code that needs the security clearance inside a "doprivileged"  function block inside ur applet , ofcourse... take a look at the code below in the next comment..

Comment: AccessController.doPrivileged(new PrivilegedAction() {

                public Object run() {
                        // It will work if your applet is signed
                        readfile();
                        return null;
                }

        });  ......... this applet code solved my problem. now running my code under the privileged code section gets me all the security clearance that i need !! .... thanks a lot for ur input there , 00jt :)

Answer (score 0):

```
AccessController.doPrivileged(new PrivilegedAction() 
     { 
         public Object run() 
         { // It will work if your applet is signed 
            readfile(); 
            return null; 
         } 
     }
);
```

......... this applet code solved my problem. now running my code under the privileged code section gets me all the security clearance that i need!